# Check ISO for errors without MD5 and how to find MD5 for online file

Tags: iso-image, md5

I was downloading a Windows AIO ISO and the page where I downloaded it from i.e., http://getintopc.com/softwares/operating-systems/windows-7-8-1-10-aio-70in1-iso-free-download/ didn't provide the MD5. The file's almost 10 GB. Now, I'd like to know two things:-
1. Once the file's downloaded, is there a way I could check for errors given I don't know the original MD5.
2. Is there a way I could get the MD5 checksum by placing the URL in a website?

Comment: Hmm. Is this website actually offering legal downloads?

Comment: According to [malwarebytes](https://www.malwarebytes.org/): "Getintopc.com is blacklisted for distributing warez. Using such sites heighten the risk of downloading/installing malware and PUP's."

Answer (score 1):

The MD5 is used to verify that the file hasn't changed from its original state, for example, the item that has been uploaded is the same as the item you have now downloaded, with no alteration between. Just getting the MD5 for the file you've downloaded is useless without an original one to compare it to (there are many tools to get the MD5 for a file, Microsoft have information on one [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/889768)). Once you have the MD5, you could check it was identical to one provided.

The easiest way to check if there are any problems would be using a utility such as [7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) which has the capabilities to test the integrity of archives. Alternatively you could just extract it and see if any errors flag up during extraction.

Note that this particular ISO, not being an official Microsoft release, could easily contain malicious items, and should be used with caution. There is little you can do, short of extracting and virus checking it's contents which may reveal something, to find out if the installations are legitimate.

Comment: Thanks for that. I've already tried extracting it with 7zip. And, it didn't give me any errors. And, I did post on the website for the MD5. Nobody has responded yet.

Answer (score -1):

Getintopc is a scam. They work with Google and I had to take disable ad blocker.  They run spoof sites too. The download stops near the end and it finished 20mb short. I use woeusb reported this. I tried again with many too delisious to be true iso. And yes it wasted my bandwidth and I think the inbred pesos askinazi has tentacles in everything.

Comment: Welcone on the SU! I suggest to focus your answer to answer the question on the top. Make it so obvious, as you only can. I don't understand your last sentence. I edited your post to increase the probability that it won't be deleted.